# How to read characters in specified range with xxd?

Tags: bash, xxd

The argument  -l means:stop after writing  octets.

```
xxd -l 120 -c 10 test.txt
```

The command will read characters in the range :from 0 (beginning) till 119 ,10 bytes per line in the file  test.txt.

```
xxd -l 140 -c 10 test.txt
```

The command will read characters in the range :from 0 (beginning) till 139 ,10 bytes per line in the file  test.txt.

How to read all characters in the range :from 119 till 139 with xxd?

Comment: -s [+][-]seek  start at <seek> bytes abs. (or +: rel.) infile offset. xxd -s 119 -l 20

Comment: @VadimPonomarev: You should put that up as an answer!